# Running Spark Standalone from Intellij Missing Dependency

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Not totally sure I understand why when I run my spark app through intellij with master as my standalone cluster url running locally with one worker I get a class not found issue but if I use just `local[*]` it works fine. I understand conceptually that perhaps my worker isn't finding the jar file with standalone but how would I ensure that my dependencies defined in my pom file get utilized in my cluster? (I'm not running `spark-submit --jars` so trying to just be able to test from within intellij using my local cluster in standalone mode.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

Comment: What contains your pom.xml?

Comment: I just have all of my dependencies ie. spark etc. with `compile` scope.